# User input list in vector and passing it in another function

Tags: function, vector, user-input

I am trying to take a list input as a vector and try to use it instead of an array. I am also trying to pass it to another function, but it is not working. what should be done?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OzwLl.png)

````
```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

void display(vector<int> v){
     for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
    {
        cout<<v[i]<<" ";
    }
}

int main(){
    vector<int> v;
    int a;
    cout<<"Enter the list: "<<endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
    {
        cin>>a;
        v.push_back(a);
    }
    display(v);

}
```
````

This is my first time so forgive me for any kind of inconvenience and help me to reduce them.